# How to escape special characters in a Jinja2 macro?

Tags: escaping, jinja2, salt-stack

I'm writing a macro that returns a cronjob syntax, something like this:

```
{%- macro passive_check(state, service) -%}
{%- set state_checks = salt['monitoring.discover_checks_passive'](state) %}
{% for host in pillar['shinken_pollers'] %}
*/{{ state_checks[service]['passive_interval'] }} * * * * nagios output=$({{ state_checks[service]['check_command'] }}); return_code=$?; printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" "{{ grains['id'] }}" "{{ service }}" "$return_code" "$output" | /usr/local/nagios/bin/py_send_nsca -H {{ host }} -c /etc/send_nsca.conf
{%- endfor -%}
{%- endmacro %}
```

then in a `.sls` file it is called as:

```
{% from 'nrpe/passive.sls' import passive_check with context %}

{%- for state in pillar['monitoring']['states'] -%}
{%- for name in salt['monitoring.discover_checks_passive'](state) %}
/etc/cron.d/passive-checks:
  file:
    - append
    - text: |
      {{ passive_check(state, name)|safe }}
{%- endfor -%}
{%- endfor %}
```

but I got the below error when running:

```
    Rendering SLS rsyslog.nrpe failed, render error: while scanning an alias
  in "<unicode string>", line 29, column 1:
    */5 * * * * nagios output=$(/usr ... 
    ^
expected alphabetic or numeric character, but found '/'
  in "<unicode string>", line 29, column 2:
    */5 * * * * nagios output=$(/usr/ ... 
     ^
```

Manual escaping with [`|e`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#working-with-manual-escaping) also returns the same error.

So the question is: how to escape these characters: *, /, ... in a Jinja2 macro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be surprised but no need to escape these characters.

The culprit that causes the error `expected alphabetic or numeric character, but found '/'` is... [whitespace control](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#whitespace-control). Pay attention to the macro:

```
{%- set state_checks = salt['monitoring.discover_checks_passive'](state) %}
{% for host in pillar['shinken_pollers'] %}
*/{{ state_checks[service]['passive_interval'] }} * * * * nagios output=$({{ state_checks[service]['check_command'] }}); return_code=$?; printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" "{{ grains['id'] }}" "{{ service }}" "$return_code" "$output" | /usr/local/nagios/bin/py_send_nsca -H {{ host }} -c /etc/send_nsca.conf
```

Without minus sign (`-`) at the end of the `set` and `for` block, it will be rendered to something like:

```
/etc/cron.d/passive-checks:
  file:
    - append
    - text: |


*/5 * * * * nagios output=$/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -c 1:1 -C rsyslogd -u syslog; return_code=$?; printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" "q-mail" "rsyslogd_proc
s" "$return_code" "$output" | /usr/local/nagios/bin/py_send_nsca -H host1 -c /etc/send_nsca.conf
*/5 * * * * nagios output=$/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -c 1:1 -C rsyslogd -u syslog; return_code=$?; printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" "q-mail" "rsyslogd_proc
s" "$return_code" "$output" | /usr/local/nagios/bin/py_send_nsca -H host2 -c /etc/send_nsca.conf
```

So you have to remove the blank lines:

```
{%- macro passive_check(state, service) -%}
{%- set state_checks = salt['monitoring.discover_checks_passive'](state) -%}
{%- for host in pillar['shinken_pollers'] -%}
*/{{ state_checks[service]['passive_interval'] }} * * * * nagios output=$({{ state_checks[service]['check_command'] }}); return_code=$?; printf "\%s\t\%s\t\%s\t\%s\n" "{{ grains['id'] }}" "{{ service }}" "$return_code" "$output" | /usr/local/nagios/bin/py_send_nsca -H {{ host }} -c /etc/send_nsca.conf
{% endfor -%}
{%- endmacro %}
```

*(Notice that I have to escape the percent sign to make it work in crontab)*

and put an indentation when calling in `file.append` state:

```
{%- for state in pillar['monitoring']['states'] -%}
{%- for name in salt['monitoring.discover_checks_passive'](state) %}
/etc/cron.d/passive-checks:
  file:
    - append
    - text: |
        {{ passive_check(state, name)|indent(8) }}
    - require:
      - file: touch_cron
{%- endfor -%}
{%- endfor %}
```